# Efficient way to fetch records since a given criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to implement a logic where the user can say give me n records since a given id#. E.g.

```
SELECT TOP (100) col1, col2, ... colN 
FROM Table1
WHERE ID > @id
ORDER BY ID
```

Performance is the biggest issue here, especially when you get into nested loops for complex joins. I've looked at the new `OFFSET-FETCH` feature in SQL Server 2012 but they require you to specify a number rather than a WHERE clause. I wouldn't know the offset unless I count num rows beforehand.

Is there an alternate way to do this efficiently in SQL Server (2008 R2 and above)?

**Update: Complete SQL as generated by EF Code first**

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p__linq__0 BigInt = 60375518904121
DECLARE @p__linq__1 BigInt = 60375518904121
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
[Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project3].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project3].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project3].[C3] AS [C3] 
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C2],
    [Limit1].[TmId] AS [TmId], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[TmId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C3]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (100) [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], [Project2].[TmId] AS [TmId], [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], [Project2].[C2] AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent2].[TmId] AS [TmId], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[TmId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
            1 AS [C2]
            FROM  [dbo].[TextMessages] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Tms] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[TmId]
            WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[Tmr] AS [Extent3]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[TmId]) AND ([Extent3].[IsDel] = 1) AND ([Extent3].[UserId] = @p__linq__0)
            )) OR ([Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] = @p__linq__1)
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Tmr] AS [Extent4] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent4].[TmId]
)  AS [Project3]
ORDER BY [Project3].[Id] DESC, [Project3].[TmId] ASC, [Project3].[C3] ASC
```

**Update:**
The real bottleneck turned out to be network latency caused by EC2 servers.

Comment: As long as you have an appropriate index on `ID`, I don't think the `top (n) ... where ID > @id` construct is going to be your problem. It sounds like you need to tune the complex joins.

Comment: Your example does not contain a complex join nor a nested loop. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @SebastianMeine: I'm going thru EF Code First and I guess part of the delay is on EF's side as well. Nevertheless, I'll post the actual query soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a bit to what @SQLFox said if ID happens to be the clustered index then it should be blazing fast.  Even if it isn't the clustered index, if it is even included in an index then you are libel to at least get an index scan and go fairly quickly.

If I had to guess I would say it's your ORDER BY that is slowing you down.  With the ORDER BY in place it's going to have to check every row and check to see if it should be part of that top 100.  Without it SQL is just going to check enough rows until it gets 100 of them that match the criteria.

Comment: Its  the primary key and I see a clustered index scan. Without order by, it's just going to return 100 random rows and not the top 100.

Comment: True, although with a clustered index scan it should be going blindingly fast.  It should go from the top of the index down 100 rows.  Are there any other join's in the query or is it just what you have listed?

Comment: Try creating an index on `TextMessages(CreatedBy_Id, Id)` and `Tmr(UserId, Id, IsDel)`.  I'm assuming that `Tms.TmId` is the clustered index, or at least an index.  If not create that also.
These are just a possibility, but they are worth testing.

Comment: Well its doing all index scans. Tms.TmID is part of a clustered index (TmId, Id). However, those are inside nested loops and majority of query time is spent there.

Comment: Adding those indexes didn't help in any significant improvement. One odd thing is it improved the performance many fold on my local box (which has a replica of prod in terms of volume). Does the edition of SQL Server matter? The test DB I have setup on PROD is running SQL Express in Amazon EC2 environment.

Comment: Edition shouldn't matter.  Check to make sure your structures are identical.  You may have additional indexes or something else different in PROD.

Comment: Yeah I took care of that. I compared the plans and they look exactly the same. Yet the query on my local takes 28ms and on prod takes 838ms (via SQL Server client statistics tab).

Comment: Try updating your statistics on your production tables.

Comment: So I ran the same query in PROD directly - takes roughly 200ms. When run remotely, takes 2500ms. I suspect EC2 is behind this sluggishness.

Comment: Np, hope it actually helped.